# Printing an Excel File in PHP

Tags: php, excel, xls

So I've got multiple instances of an application running, one for 2008, 2009, 2010.. 2012. All of these have a feature where you can download a .XLS report of a bunch of data. For some reason, the XLS file is being mangled when downloaded through the application. You can move the pdf to the webroot, download it, and it will open just fine, but when you attempt to download it through, say, `download.php?file=29320f9je`, Excel says it doesn't recognize the file's format, and spews garbage (what SHOULD be our data, just in unicode trash)

Anyone run into this before and have other suggestions to check, other than the application and headers? Because the code between 2010 and 2012 SHOULD be fine.

### Use Example:

User generates report. Can be viewed properly via above method. Actual method is as follows:

User clicks link to "download file" (`report.retrieve.download.htm?file=2390jsf`)

report.retrieve.download.htm

```
$file = $_GET['file'];

$tempfile = new tempfile(''); // open tempfile class, argument is name of report

if ($tempfile->set_filename($file) === false)
        $tempfile->error_report('4026','',"Filename: $file",'Y');

if ($tempfile->send_file() === false)
        $tempfile->error_report('4027','',"Filename: $file",'Y');
```

Associated function

```
public function send_file() {
            $file = $this->get_full_filename();
            if (file_exists($file)===FALSE)
                    return FALSE;
            if ($this->send_headers($file)===FALSE)
                    return FALSE;
            $this->output_file($file);
            return TRUE;
    }
```

And that all important headers function..

```
public function send_headers($filename) {
            if (headers_sent()===TRUE)
                    return FALSE;
            if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && preg_match("/MSIE/", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
                    // IE Bug in download name workaround
                    ini_set( 'zlib.output_compression','Off' );
            }
            /*
            $fInfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
            $type = $fInfo->file($filename);
            $stats = stat($filename);
            $size = $stats['size'];
            */
            $output_filename = $this->get_output_filename();

            if (eregi('csv$', $this->get_output_filename())) {
                    header("Content-type: text/csv");
                    //header("Content-Size: $size");
                    header("Pragma: public");
                    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$output_filename");
            }
            elseif (eregi('htm$', $this->get_output_filename()))
                    header("Content-type: text/html");
            else {
                    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
                    //header("Content-Size: $size");
                    header("Pragma: public");
                    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
                    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$output_filename");
            }
            return TRUE;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sending correct headers?

Comment: Checked the headers already. They haven't changed since 2008.

Comment: So how is the xls file created? Or is it a pdf? or a pdf with a .xls extension? or an xls file with a pdf extension?

Comment: *How* are you enabling that download? It's all about the details, and currently you offer none.

Comment: It's created by another script, and it's an excel file / .xls; again, I can download and view the temporary file just fine when not going through the application.

Comment: What is the code for download.php what browser/os are you using you download?

Comment: Edited code for a few things into the post; download attempted using safari, chrome, firefox, and ie.

Comment: Don't use ereg functions. They're deprecated. Also make sure that no PHP warnings are being output before the excel data is dumped. That'll corrupt the "file" received by the client.

Comment: /etc/php.ini: display_errors = Off

Comment: Open the downloaded file in a text editor, and look for leading or trailing blank spaces or PHP error messages at the top or bottom of the file

Comment: Actually, I dumped the headers into the .xls file that got downloaded and saw a newline before my var_dump() ;; see my posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different file had a trailing newline; one that was an include of an include of an include. I didn't write this application, but the people who did chose to use closing PHP markers (?>) and ended up with one of these stupid bugs.

```
zipp@zeratul htdocs]# echo '<?php foreach (glob("*.php") as $file){if (preg_match( "/\\?".">\\s\\s+\\Z/m", file_get_contents($file))) echo("$file\n");} ?>' | php
config.class.php
```